# Error en procedimiento almacenado MySQL - Python

Tags: mysql, python, stored-procedure

Tengo este procedimiento en MySQL:

```
sql_procedure = """CALL INSERTAR_OPORTUNIDAD(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""" % (
    CLIENTE,CLIENTEOCA,DENCLIENTE,AGRUPACION,DESAGRUPACION,CIUDAD,DESCIUDAD,
    PROVINCIA,DESPROVINCIA,DOMICILIO,TELEFONO1,TELEFONO2,FAX,EMAIL,CAMPOPERSO1,
    INACTIVO,TIPO,DESTIPO,SIGLAINFO,TIPOMOV,DEBCRE,LETRA,PUNTOVTA,NUMERO,FECHA_EMI,
    FECHA_VTO,PORDESCUENTO,DESCUENTO,NETO,PORPERIVA,PERIVA,PORPERIB,PERIB,
    PORPERMUNCBA,PERMUNCBA,TOTAL,TOTALSIMP,CANCELADO,SINAPLICAR,
    ESTADO,VENDEDOR,DENVENDEDOR,TRANSPORTISTA,DENTRANSPORTISTA,
    REDESPACHO,DENREDESPACHO,COMENTARIOS,REFERENCIAS,
    COD_ITEM,DES_ITEM,MEMO_ITEM,NRO_ITEM,FECHAENTREGA,CANTI,CANTI_COMPE,CANTI_SINCOMPE,PREUNI_NETO,
    PREUNI_FINAL,PREUNI_NETO_BONIFI,PREUNI_FINAL_BONIFI,BONIFI_POR,BONIFI,SUBTOTDESCUENTO,TOTPORPER,
    SUBTOTPER,IMPO_SUBTOT_SINIVA,IMPO_SUBTOT_CONIVA,IVA_GRAL,TIPOIMPUIN,PORCEIMPUIN,IMPU_IN,ESTADOITEM,
    CPTESDESTIASIGNACION,CODUNIDAD,NUMDOCU)
cursor_procedure= conMysql.cursor()
cursor_procedure.execute(sql_procedure)
cursor_procedure.commit()
cursor_procedure.close()
```

Cuando lo ejecuto en Python tengo este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filemysql.py", line 303, in <module>
    CPTESDESTIASIGNACION,CODUNIDAD,NUMDOCU)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2):

El error dice cuál es el problema, no le estás pasando la cantidad de `%s` necesarias para formatear el string. Según veo te sobra uno, el código debería ser así:

```
sql_procedure = """CALL INSERTAR_OPORTUNIDAD(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""" % (
    CLIENTE,CLIENTEOCA,DENCLIENTE,AGRUPACION,DESAGRUPACION,CIUDAD,DESCIUDAD,
    PROVINCIA,DESPROVINCIA,DOMICILIO,TELEFONO1,TELEFONO2,FAX,EMAIL,CAMPOPERSO1,
    INACTIVO,TIPO,DESTIPO,SIGLAINFO,TIPOMOV,DEBCRE,LETRA,PUNTOVTA,NUMERO,FECHA_EMI,
    FECHA_VTO,PORDESCUENTO,DESCUENTO,NETO,PORPERIVA,PERIVA,PORPERIB,PERIB,
    PORPERMUNCBA,PERMUNCBA,TOTAL,TOTALSIMP,CANCELADO,SINAPLICAR,
    ESTADO,VENDEDOR,DENVENDEDOR,TRANSPORTISTA,DENTRANSPORTISTA,
    REDESPACHO,DENREDESPACHO,COMENTARIOS,REFERENCIAS,
    COD_ITEM,DES_ITEM,MEMO_ITEM,NRO_ITEM,FECHAENTREGA,CANTI,CANTI_COMPE,CANTI_SINCOMPE,PREUNI_NETO,
    PREUNI_FINAL,PREUNI_NETO_BONIFI,PREUNI_FINAL_BONIFI,BONIFI_POR,BONIFI,SUBTOTDESCUENTO,TOTPORPER,
    SUBTOTPER,IMPO_SUBTOT_SINIVA,IMPO_SUBTOT_CONIVA,IVA_GRAL,TIPOIMPUIN,PORCEIMPUIN,IMPU_IN,ESTADOITEM,
    CPTESDESTIASIGNACION,CODUNIDAD,NUMDOCU)
cursor_procedure= conMysql.cursor()
cursor_procedure.execute(sql_procedure)
cursor_procedure.commit()
cursor_procedure.close()
```

Comment: Gracias @jemonge, mi cabeza ya no da mas!!! Solo faltaba sacarle un %s.

Answer (score 2):

Hay un par de cosas que podrías modificar para mejorar un poco tu script:

1. Lo más seguro es que en vez de formatear los parámetros directamente en tu variable `sql_procedure`, los pases a la misma función `execute`:

   ```
   cursor_procedure.execute(sql_procedure, params)
   ```

   Esto implicaría que tengas la lista de parametros de esta forma:

   ```
   params = [
       CLIENTE,
       CLIENTEOCA,
       # ...
   ]
   ```
2. En vez de estar escribiendo `%s` por cada uno puedes formatearlo de acuerdo a la cantidad total de parámetros. Por ejemplo:

   ```
   >>> sql = '''CALL INSERTAR_OPORTUNIDAD(%s)'''
   >>> params = [10,20,30,40]
   >>> sql % ','.join(['%s' for p in params])
   'CALL INSERTAR_OPORTUNIDAD(%s,%s,%s,%s)'
   ```

Si juntamos lo anterior en tu script, tendrías:

```
params = [
    CLIENTE,
    CLIENTEOCA,
    # ...
]

# Por cada parámetro en params se crea su respectivo %s
sql_procedure = 'CALL INSERTAR_OPORTUNIDAD(%s)' % ','.join(['%s' for p in params])

cursor_procedure= conMysql.cursor()
cursor_procedure.execute(sql_procedure, params)
cursor_procedure.commit()
cursor_procedure.close()
```

Comment: Excelente!! Gracias @Cesar!!